# how to give calendar permissions administratively? Outlook 2010/Exchange 2010

Tags: outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

So whenever we get a new employee, we usually have to login to their rds account, open their outlook and give groups or individuals certain permissions / access (reviewer, editor, etc) to their calendar. Is there a way to automate this so the first time they log on these permissions are inherited and saves us the time? Thanks and I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [Add-MailboxFolderPermission](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298062(v=exchg.141).aspx) cmdlet in Exchange Management Shell. The account running it will need to have Full Access to the target mailboxes in order to logon to the mailbox and apply the appropriate permissions at the folder level, but that can be granted just before the folder permissions are applied, then removed afterwards.